# Kogito process and root process link

Tags: kogito

We have requirement to merge few processes.
Assume there is parent process investigation and it spins off child process audit. Now there are 5 investigation process with 5 audit sub processes. While looking at the 1at process user determine that they would now club all 5 audit processes linked to 1st investigation process

How to do that. I see root process in kogito, shall i upeadte root pid for rest 4 processes. Please advise how to move processes from one parent to another

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach would be to actually model this as part of the process, so you could signal the process to "hand-off" the 5 audit to a new instance. That way these sub instances and parent process can gracefully finish and a running instance would take over the new data. So looking more from the domain or information perspective rather than the actual technical process. So something like sending the audit id from the current process instance and on the other end, it would receive that id, load the audit data into the current process instance, and spinning new sub-instances if you like.

Comment: Thanks @cristiano-nicolai will give it a shot. It seems definitive and reasonable.